# Android Mediaplayer Won't Stop

Tags: android, button, audio

I have the following code to play an mp3 file from the web and this is working but when I use the stop functionality the audio does not stop. Can anyone point me towards a resource to find out more about this or tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
showAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        if (!showAudio.getText().equals("Stop")) {
            try {
                String url = lblAudio.getText().toString();
                if (url.length() > 2) {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    showAudio.setText("Stop");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, there was a problem playing audio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            showAudio.setText("Audio");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new MediaPlayer every time you click the button. Create the player outside of the click handler.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed this and it seems to be working one time (It will play and stop but if I press play again I get an IllegalStateException).

Comment: The illegal state exception is because you are releasing the player. See the [state diagram here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). Call `reset` where you are currently calling `release`, and since you are calling `setDataSource` and `prepare` each time before `start` it should work fine. Call `release` when you are actually done with the player, e.g., in the `onStop` of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out :

> ```
>  try { 
>      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
>       {
>        mediaPlayer.stop();
>        mediaPlayer.release(); 
>        }
>        } catch(Exception ex) { 
>              ex.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but unfortunately the audio is still playing when I click stop.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code ? Does it goes inside this condition ?

Comment: Yes I have debugged the code and it is going into the condition. The suggestion that @Dave made seems to have fixed the problem but the audio will only play & stop once.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your media player a global variable and make it static....

Answer (score 0):

I have a working media player that starts and stops

```
Uri ringtone;
MediaPlayer mp;

ringtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), ringtone);

    //code to start the mediaplayer

     if (Flags.notificationReceived) {
                        showAlert(Flags.patientModel);
                        Flags.notificationReceived = false;
                        mp.start();
                        mp.setLooping(true);
                        vibrate(2000);
                    }

    //code to stop the media player

     if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), ringtone);


   }
```